I want to change the position of the child row in the Tabulator grid
When I press the down button in a row, I am creating a function that moves the position of that row to the bottom of the row immediately below it. When I press the down button on the row where row_nm is First, it moves normally. However, when I press the down button on the row where row_nm is Ready1. When I press it, no errors are checked and it doesn't work.
It works for rows without a tree structure applied, but does not work for rows with a tree structure applied. I'm curious about the solution. I'm using Tabulator version 4.9. thank you
function click_downIcon(e, cell){
   var row = cell.getRow();
   var nextRow = row.getNextRow();
   var rowData = row.getData();
   var nextRowData = nextRow.getData();

   if(rowData.level == nextRowData.level){
     tGrid_1.moveRow(row, nextRow, false);
   }else{
     alert("not the same level")
   }
}


var jsonData = [
{"list_cd" : "0", "row_nm" : "First", "col_nm" : "First", "level" : 0, "id" : 0, "up_id" : 0, "seq" : 0},
{"list_cd" : "0-1", "row_nm" : "Start", "col_nm" : "Start", "level" : 0, "id" : 1, "up_id" : 0, "seq" : 0},
{"list_cd" : "0-1-1", "row_nm" : "Ready", "col_nm" : "Ready", "level" : 1, "id" : 2, "up_id" : 0, "seq" : 1, _ childern:[
{"list_cd" : "0-1-1", "row_nm" : "Ready1", "col_nm" : "Ready1", "level" : 2, "id" : 3, "up_id" : 1, "seq" : 1},
{"list_cd" : "0-1-2", "row_nm" : "Ready2", "col_nm" : "Ready2", "level" : 2, "id" : 4, "up_id" : 1, "seq" : 2},
]}

